# A showInputDialog on my Update button

Tags: java

### Here is a program for the currency converter we are working on

We wanted to make the update button pop-up the input dialog and get the input dialog's data to multiply into the first input - (convertFrom) by clicking the compute button.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Panel extends Frame implements ItemListener, ActionListener { 

    //iniatialized all the GUI components
    JComboBox convertFrom, convertTo;
    JTextField txtFrom, txtTo;
    JButton compute, exit, update;
    JLabel from, to;
    JLabel lblFrom, lblTo;
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    double input = 0;
    double result = 0;
    double num1 = 0;

    public Panel() { 
        //add all the GUI components
        //LAYOUT for the program, not included in the main operation
        super("Money Currency Converter: By - Lapiña's Group"); 
        setSize(420,335);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        lblFrom = new JLabel("From:");
        lblFrom.setBounds(30,45,250,30);
        lblFrom.setForeground(Color.black);
        add(lblFrom);

        convertFrom = new JComboBox();
        convertFrom.setBounds(30,70,150,30);
        convertFrom.addItem("Philippine Peso");
        convertFrom.addItem("Japanese Yen");
        convertFrom.addItem("US Dollar");
        convertFrom.addItem("British Pound");
        convertFrom.addItem("Euro");
        add(convertFrom);

        lblTo = new JLabel("To:");
        lblTo.setBounds(230,45,250,30);
        lblTo.setForeground(Color.black);
        add(lblTo);

        convertTo = new JComboBox();
        convertTo.setBounds(230,70,150,30);
        convertTo.addItem("Philippine Peso");
        convertTo.addItem("Japanese Yen");
        convertTo.addItem("US Dollar");
        convertTo.addItem("British Pound");
        convertTo.addItem("Euro");
        add(convertTo);

        txtFrom = new JTextField(15);
        txtFrom.setBounds(50,140,300,30);
        add(txtFrom);

        update = new JButton("Update");
        update.setBounds(50,250,100,30);
        add(update);

        compute = new JButton("Compute");
        compute.setBounds(150,250,100,30);
        add(compute);

        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setBounds(250,250,100,30);
        add(exit);

        from = new JLabel("Enter Amount to Convert:");
        from.setForeground(Color.black);
        from.setBounds(50,110,300,30);
        add(from);

        to = new JLabel("Total Amount Converted:");
        to.setForeground(Color.black);
        to.setBounds(50,170,300,30);
        add(to);   

        txtTo = new JTextField(15);
        txtTo.setBounds(50,200,300,30);
        txtTo.setEditable(false);
        txtTo.setForeground(Color.black);
        add(txtTo);

        //register all the GUI components who will LISTEN or INVOKE the methods
        convertFrom.addItemListener(this);
        convertTo.addItemListener(this);
        compute.addActionListener(this);
        txtFrom.addActionListener(this);
        update.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

        //this will close the applet window if the user clicked the close or exit button
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { 
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { 
                    exit(); 
                } 
            });
    }
    //the exit method
    public void exit(){ 
        setVisible(false); 
        dispose(); 
        System.exit(0); 
    } 
    //show or make the applet window frame visible

    //the main body of calculating the currency
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Panel w = new Panel(); 
        w.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void UpdatedInput() {

    if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Philippine Peso")
        {
            result = (input * num1);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Japanese Yen")
        {
            result = (input * num1);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="US Dollar")
        {
            result = (input * num1);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="British Pound")
        {
            result = (input * num1);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Euro")
        {
            result = (input * num1);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number For Updated Currency: ");
        }
    }

    public void ConvertPeso() {
        if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Philippine Peso")
        {
            result = (input);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Japanese Yen")
        {
            result = (input * 2.16);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="US Dollar")
        {
            result = (input * 0.020);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="British Pound")
        {
            result = (input * 0.015);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else 
        {
            result = (input * 0.016);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
    }

    public void ConvertYen() {
        if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Philippine Peso")
        {
            result = (input * 0.46);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Japanese Yen")
        {
            result = (input);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="US Dollar")
        {
            result = (input * 0.0090);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="British Pound")
        {
            result = (input * 0.0070);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = (input * 0.0076);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
    }

    public void ConvertDollar() {
        if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Philippine Peso")
        {
            result = (input * 51.20);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Japanese Yen")
        {
            result = (input * 110.53);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="US Dollar")
        {
            result = (input);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="British Pound")
        {
            result = (input * 0.78);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = (input * 0.84);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
    }

    public void ConvertPound() {
        if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Philippine Peso")
        {
            result = (input * 66.04);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Japanese Yen")
        {
            result = (input * 142.56);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="US Dollar")
        {
            result = (input * 1.29);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="British Pound")
        {
            result = (input);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = (input * 1.08);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
    }

    public void ConvertEuro() {
        if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Philippine Peso")
        {
            result = (input * 60.88);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="Japanese Yen")
        {
            result = (input * 131.37);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="US Dollar")
        {
            result = (input * 1.19);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else if(convertTo.getSelectedItem()=="British Pound")
        {
            result = (input * 0.92);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
        else
        {
            result = (input);
            txtTo.setText(""+result);
        }
    }

    //the correction part of choosing the from-choice and the to-choice
    //connecting the main operation or the "public void strings"
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        input = Double.parseDouble(txtFrom.getText());
        String msg = txtFrom.getText();

        if(e.getSource()==compute)
        {
            if(convertFrom.getSelectedItem()=="Philippine Peso")
            {
                ConvertPeso();                 
            }
            else if(convertFrom.getSelectedItem()=="Japanese Yen")
            {
                ConvertYen();
            }
            else if(convertFrom.getSelectedItem()=="US Dollar")
            {
                ConvertDollar();
            }
            else if(convertFrom.getSelectedItem()=="British Pound")
            {
                ConvertPound();
            }
            else if(convertFrom.getSelectedItem()=="Euro")
            {
                ConvertEuro();
            }
            else
            {
                UpdatedInput();
            }

        }
        //this will asked the user to exit or not
        else
        {
            //this will display a confirm dialog box
            //exit button on confirm dialog do not work until detects an input
            int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you really want to quit?","Exit",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(choice==0) {
                dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {

    }
    }
```

What should we do to get the input of input dialog?

> hope works

Comment: What input do you give the JTextField? By the way, try to use switch instead of all those if() elseif().

Comment: txtFrom, txtTo.

Comment: No I mean what do you insert into the TextField? It has to be convertable to double.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Out of personal curiosity, what's the benefit of case-switch over if-else in a situation like this?

Comment: @SassyRegards201 Well for once it looks a lot cleaner and gives a way better overview. But the biggest thing is that it avoids code duplication. For example if he decides to use a different method for comparsion he would need to edit each else-if clause. By using switch he would just need to change the header and would be done with it.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Ahh makes much more sense. Thank you so much. One last question, when do I know when to use a switch and when to use if. I've personally only used switch in a school assignment but never in any of my own programs.

Comment: @SassyRegards201 That´s a bit tricky to answer. The most important thing is just to think about the issue with code duplication. It´s something that comes with experience I guess.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim thanks! Probably good to go practices switches now. :)